# REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW suddenly taking more time to complete

Tags: postgresql

We have a materialized view in our Postgres DB (11.12, managed by AWS RDS). We have a scheduled task that updates it every 5 minutes using `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW <view_name>`. At some specific point last week, the time needed to refresh the view suddenly went from ~1s to ~20s. The view contains ~70k rows, with around 15 columns, all of them being integers, booleans or UUIDs.

Prior to this:

- There were no changes in the server configuration.
- There were no changes to the view itself. In fact, running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <expression used to create the view>` returns that the query still gets executed in less than a second. If the query is ran with a client like Postico, it takes ~20s to fetch all the results (a bit consistent with the time needed to materialize it, although we assume this is due to the time needed for network transmission).
- There were no changes in the schema or any significant record increase in the contents of the tables needed to compute the view.
- RDS Performance Insights indicate that the query is mostly using CPU resources

I know this is probably not enough to get a solution, but:

- Are there any server performance metrics or logs that could lead us to understand better this situation?
- Is this just the normal time the server needs to persist the view to disk? If so, any idea of possible reasons why it started to take so long recently?

[Here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/pBAy) is a link to the execution plan.

EDIT: creating another materialized view with the same `JOINS` but selecting less columns performs as expected (~1s).

EDIT 2: setting `enable_nestloop = false` greatly speeds up the `REFRESH` operation (same performance as before). Would this indicate that refactoring the underlying query could solve the issue?

Comment: Take the underlying query and run that with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. Then add the query and the result to the question.

Comment: You can't EXPLAIN a REFRESH directly, but you can use the auto_explain extension to capture the plan used by the refresh.  If you first do `set client_min_messages TO log;` you can even get the plan output to the client.  Then compare that plan to the one obtained from running the query itself.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you can check the query and he result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/pBAy).

Comment: That query took less than a second. Is that too long?

Comment: Is the RDS performance insight that show mostly CPU for the actual refresh, or for running the query in standalone outside of the MV?

Comment: @jjanes for the actual `REFRESh` operation.

Comment: Did someone create some new indexes on the MV, which take a long time to rebuild?  The REFRESH was not shown the be done CONCURRENTLY.  Is it accurate (that it is *not* done CONCURRENTLY)?

Comment: Not really, we haven't identified any changes in the schema, indexes or the underlying query. Correct, we are not using `CONCURRENTLY`.

Comment: I made a couple of edits to the questions with some findings.

Answer (score 2):

Try REFRESH materialized view concurrently.
When you refresh data for a materialized view, PostgreSQL locks the entire table therefore you cannot query data against it. To avoid this, you can use the CONCURRENTLY option.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY view_name;
```

With CONCURRENTLY option, PostgreSQL creates a temporary updated version of the materialized view, compares two versions, and performs INSERT and UPDATE only the differences.

You can query against a materialized view while it is being updated. One requirement for using CONCURRENTLY option is that the materialized view must have a UNIQUE index.

Comment: Note that this will take longer time to refresh the view but it will allow querying from user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770152/postgresql-refresh-materialized-views-concurrently#:~:text=From%20the%20Postgres%20source%20code%3A

Answer (score 2):

Original poster here. This is more than a year old, but here's what happened and how we eventually fixed it.

TLDR:

-`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW <query>` started to take much longer than executing the query used to construct the view (~1s vs ~20s).

After a couple of weeks this question was asked, the query itself started to behave similarly (taking ~20s to complete). At this point, the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` started to show indications of performance issues with the query. So we ended up optimising the underlying query (the biggest performance gain being replacing some `JOINS` with a `CTE`).

After this, the performance of both the `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW <query>` and the standalone query behaved correctly (execution time < 1s).

A still open question here is why the `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW <query>` and the standalone `query` had different performance at some point in time? Was the DB query planner choosing different query plans depending on whether it was going to materialize the view or not? I guess if someone knows if such thing is possible, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use PG_IVM extention for incremental updating materilized view

Sometimes when we refresh the materialized view it takes a long time to finish but we need an immediate refresh for that reason we can use the PG_IVM extension.

PG_IVM EXTENTIONUN INSTALLATION:

```
yum install postgresql15-devel --nobest
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-15/bin
cd /install/pg_ivm-1.5.1/

make install


postgres=# create extension pg_ivm ;
CREATE EXTENSION

create table employee 
(id numeric, name text,surname text,age numeric);
create table employee_position 
(id numeric, emp_id numeric,postion_name text,status numeric);

insert into employee values ( 1,'Valeh','Agayev',37);
insert into employee values ( 2,'Eltun','Hajiyev',31);
insert into employee_position values ( 1,1,'DBA',1);
insert into employee_position values ( 2,2,'DBA',1);


SELECT create_immv('myview', 'SELECT NAME,SURNAME,AGE,POSTION_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE EMP, EMPLOYEE_POSITION EPOS WHERE EPOS.EMP_ID=EMP.ID');

postgres=# update employee set age=32 where age=31;

postgres=# select * from myview ;
 name  | surname | age | postion_name
-------+---------+-----+--------------
 Valeh | Agayev  |  37 | DBA
 Eltun | Hajiyev |  31 | DBA


insert into employee values ( 3,'Temir','Gasimov',24);
insert into employee_position values ( 3,3,'DEV',1);

postgres=# select * from myview ;
 name  | surname | age | postion_name
-------+---------+-----+--------------
 Valeh | Agayev  |  37 | DBA
 Eltun | Hajiyev |  32 | DBA
 Temir | Gasimov |  24 | DEV
```

Answer (score -1):

Updates `materialized view` every time (or every 5 minutes) this is not a good way to refresh materialized. Then the meaning of using `materialized view` does not remain. Let me explain to you one of the ways I found with my own logic, based on my own experience, so you can find a more optimal way later. Assumed, we used two tables in our `materialized view`, and we need that is a changed data one of the two tables we will refresh `materialized view`. To do this during the update or delete table we must insert to the table (for example `refresh_materialized` table) one record (you can also use the trigger), through which will be performed refreshing `materialized view`

For example:

```
insert into refresh_materialized 
(
    refresh_status, 
    insert_date, 
    executed_date 
)
values (
    false,
    now(), 
    null 
)
```

And so in our schedule task, we can use this query:

```
select count(*) from refresh_materialized 
where refresh_status = false
```

if the `count(*) will be > 0` then we must refresh `materialized view` else do nothing. After the refreshing materialized view we must update this table:

```
update refresh_materialized 
set 
    refresh_status = true, 
    executed_date = now() 
where 
    refresh_status = false;
```